# node.js File System change order

Tags: node.js

I'm looping over a directory structure and it seems readdirSync() returns everything in alphabetical order. Is there a way for me to get by folder/file and then alphabetical order? Since I'm recreating the folder structure what I end up with now is a mix of folders and files together instead of grouping all folders first in alphabetical order then all files in alphabetical order which is what I would prefer.

```
function buildProjectStructure(currentPath, root){  
        var files = fs.readdirSync(currentPath);
        for(var i in files){
            var currentFile = currentPath + "/" + files[i];
            var stats = fs.statSync(currentFile);

            if(stats.isFile()){
                // todo: add file to tree view
                root.append("<li>" + files[i] + "</li>")
            }
            else if(stats.isDirectory()){
                // todo: add folder to tree view
                var folder = $("<li><input type='checkbox' id='" + files[i] + "' /><label for='" + files[i] + "'>" + files[i] + "</label>").appendTo(root)
                var folderUL = $("<ul/>").appendTo(folder);

                buildProjectStructure(currentFile, folderUL);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want folders and files in separate lists, you can just add an iteration step before your current one to put the files in one array and the folders in another.  Just a few more lines of code.

Comment: I'm not following that because there can be nested folders and files so breaking out all files to 1 list and all folders to 1 list won't show the nested hierarchy. I'll just have a list of folders and a list of files. Unless I'm not understanding correctly. I feel like I need to sort the files array before I loop over it by folder in alphabetical order then by file in alphabetical order. Any easy way to do that?

Comment: OK, so after I get the files array, I'll break that out into 2 arrays (folders/files) then sort each, then recombine them with folders entered first followed by files. That should do it. Not sure if that's sort of what you meant or not.

Answer (score 0):

So I broke the files/folders into 2 lists after getting them from readdirSync() and then combined the 2 lists back.

```
function getOrderedFoldersFiles(currentPath, files){
        var _folders = [];
        var _files = [];

        for(var i in files){
            var currentFile = currentPath + "/" + files[i];
            var stats = fs.statSync(currentFile);

            if(stats.isFile()){
                _files.push(files[i]);
            }
            else if(stats.isDirectory()){
                _folders.push(files[i]);
            }
        }

        return _folders.concat(_files);
    }

    function buildProjectStructure(currentPath, root){  
        var files = fs.readdirSync(currentPath);
        var _files = getOrderedFoldersFiles(currentPath, files);

        for(var i in _files){
            var currentFile = currentPath + "/" + _files[i];
            var stats = fs.statSync(currentFile);

            //alert(currentFile);
            if(stats.isFile()){
                // todo: add file to tree view
                root.append("<li>" + _files[i] + "</li>")
            }
            else if(stats.isDirectory()){
                // todo: add folder to tree view
                var folder = $("<li><input type='checkbox' id='" + _files[i] + "' /><label for='" + _files[i] + "'>" + _files[i] + "</label>").appendTo(root)
                var folderUL = $("<ul/>").appendTo(folder);

                buildProjectStructure(currentFile, folderUL);
            }
        }
    }
```